# How to find out if prerelease test was successful?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have just ran prelease tests on my local machine with the commands generated on http://prerelease.ros.org.

prerelease.sh finished without any error prompt and the last output was

```
No test results in overlay workspace
```

Does it mean the test was successful? (In this case a final output like "Prelease Test finished successfully." would be more clearly ;) )

Or do I have to check for anything else?

Regards
Sabrina

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/221286/how-to-find-out-if-prerelease-test-was-successful?/) by [Sabrina](https://answers.ros.org/users/307/sabrina/) on ROS Answers with karma: 285 on 2015-11-20

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> No test results in overlay workspace

IMO this particular line has nothing to do with the test result of your targetted package. The test result must have been printed way above of that line.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2016-07-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0